# how to resize widget based on content

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a draggable scrollable sheet and I want it to show the content based on how much content is currently to show in sheet for ex if I am using a visibility widget and it is visibility is false it should not show the space for it , but if it is true it should automatically resizes itself and show it on screen, I have total 4 widgets in my sheet 2 of them are in visibilty widget

Comment: User ListView Widget.

Answer (score 0):

when the visibility of widget changes you can change the minChildSize and maxChildSize of draggableScrollableSheet and  set it to a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide and unhide a widget but don't want that the hidden widget to take space on screen then instead of Visibility you should use if without any curly braces something like this.

```
Column(
  Children:[
   Text(Hello), 
   if(_isVisible) 
   SizedBox(height:200, width:500)
  ]
  )
```

If you want to add multiple column widget to be hide and show then use spread operator

```
Column(
  Children:[
   Text(Hello), 
   if(_isVisible) ...[
   SizedBox(height:200, width:500), 
   Container(height:400, width:500, 
       Color:Colors.red) 
    ]
  ])
```